# how to use object(return from controle) in jquery/javascript with asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on asp.net mvc3 asynchronous process with ado.net

In my application After updating user his profile data - next time User login to his account, in that time I want to display his default profile data(if not null) into his profile page.

1)In this scenario I unable to display user default data in dropdownlist
I am using html dropdownlist()
2)how to communicate data which is returned from control to view with jquery(give me sample ex)

Can you tel me anyone how to display user default data after update his profile. Thank you for advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can return data using json format and then parse it to javascript object: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/